# Why the QED coupling constant is a continuous function?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization

In page 316 of 'Student friendly quantum field theory', when discussing Figure 12-4, it says that the QED coupling constant is a continuous function of $\ln(p)$. But I think it's disconnected at $p=2m_u$ or $p=2m_d$ points. I'm confused.

> [image] Figure 12-4 of 'Student
>   friendly quantum field theory'

Comment: The function looks continuous. Are you asking whether it has a continuous derivative?

Comment: Why do you think it's "disconnected" at those points?

Comment: @ACuriousMind he's just confused by the graph notation with the breaks in the axes.

Comment: @DanielSank: I don't think so because neither $2m_u$ nor $2m_d$ are the points where the graph breaks.

Comment: @ACuriousMind oh, right.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the axis $\ln(p)$ has been cut into two pieces. There is a whole section missing between $p=2m_\mu$ and $p\approx 100$ GeV. This explains the apparent "discontinuity".

Comment: Note that the user says it "should" be discontinuous at $2m_u$ or $2m_d$ (but offers no reason for that). This is not where the break in the graphic is.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Fair enough. Now that you mention it there is a small discontinuity in $\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial p}$ at these points. I would guess those are just due to sloppy drawings by the author.